# mvc dll missing on Azure. What's wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to compile my project on Azure pipelines, but I got this error:

> [error]Framework\Framework.General\Controllers\ControllerWidgets.cs(5,18):
>   Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My project is a class library that is an MVC's extension.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if system.web.mvc nuget package is installed in the project or not ?

Comment: Hi Manoj, I've added this since Assemblies that are in mi local machine. this dll appeared when I installed MVC package.

Comment: Does it mean that problem is resolved ?  Or you still have problem after adding the nuget package ?

Comment: Yes, I could resolved it  retargeting Framework version on the project, and then I downloaded  the mvc package. 
But Im getting new error.
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controllers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
This namespace there arent on nuget. 
Any suggest?

Comment: Make sure the .NET framework version targeted are compatible!   For example, This may happen if .net 4.5 dll is added in .net 4.0.  Can you check the target version of System.Web.Mvc vs the target framework of your solution ?

Comment: The problem was solved, I've just installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

Comment: Great.. I am putting this same in the answer box then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the System.Web.Mvc nuget package is missing.

WHile adding this nuget package please make sure that the target framework of the package / .dll and the target framework of rest of the project dlls /exes match.